# Do "$R_*$-modules" have an accepted name?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, modules, sheaf-theory

(All my rings are commutative and unital.)

By a *module,* I mean an ordered pair $(R,M),$ where $R$ is a ring and $M$ is an $R$-module. There is a functor $$\mathbf{ur} :\mathbf{Ring} \leftarrow \mathbf{Mod}$$ that returns $R$ given $(R,M),$ namely the *underlying ring functor.*

Now let $X$ denote a topological space and $R_*$ denote a sheaf of rings on $X$. Then by an $R_*$-module, I mean a sheaf $M_*$ of modules on $X$ satisfying: $$R_* = \mathbf{ur} \circ M_*$$

> **Question.** Do "$R_*$-modules" have an accepted name?

For example, let $X$ denote a smooth manifold. Then there is a ring-theoretic sheaf $R_*$ on $X$ consisting of those smooth partial functions $\mathbb{R} \leftarrow X$ whose preimage is an open set. There is also a module-theoretic sheaf $M_*$ on $X$ consisting of those smooth partial sections of the tangent bundle whose preimage is an open set. With these definitions, $M_*$ is an $R_*$-module.

Comment: As far as I can tell, they're just called $R_{\ast}$-modules, or maybe sheaves of $R_{\ast}$-modules.

Comment: I also don't understand your example. Are you just talking about the sheaf of smooth functions $X \to \mathbb{R}$ and the sheaf of smooth sections of the tangent bundle or what? What, explicitly, are the sections of the sheaves you have in mind over an open $U$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, yes, that's right. I'm a bit uncomfortable calling them them "functions" or "sections" because they aren't necessarily defined on all of $X$. But I think we're talking about the same thing. Explicitly, given an open set $O$ of $X$, an element of $R_O$ is a partial function $\mathbb{R} \leftarrow X$ whose preimage is $O$, which is smooth in the usual sense of the word. Also, just to clarify, I use "preimage of a partial function" to mean "the subset of its domain on which it is defined."

Comment: That seems perversely nonstandard.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, which part of it?

Comment: Thinking about sections as partial functions, as opposed to just as functions with source $U$, and using "preimage" to mean the domain of definition of a partial function.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I use "preimage" because "domain of definition" is easily confused with "domain," in the sense of: "if $f : Y \leftarrow X$ is a partial function, then $X$ is called the domain of $f$." I'm not being intentionally perverse, however when I find terminology like this that seems likely to obfuscate or confuse, I do my best to fix it. Surely that is something we all (should) do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're just called $R_{\ast}$-modules, or maybe sheaves of $R_{\ast}$-modules. This is an important and basic notion in algebraic geometry, where $R_{\ast}$ will typically be the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ of a scheme $X$.